# Needed Access token to hit google api from windows application

Tags: c#, google-api, desktop-application

I need to hit below api. When i tried using fiddler i have faced authentication error. so, I understand  that i need to pass accesstoken in the request

`https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{parent=devices/*/deviceUsers}:lookup`

I need to fetch accesstoken for windows desktop application.

Error when i hit request without accesstoken:-

```
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Comment: One does not "just" fetch an access token, access tokens just be created.  Please edit your question and include your code so that we can see how you are attempting to generate this access token currently.   Im curious as to how you think fidler would create an access token for you?

Comment: A URL can contain parameters which are after the question mark like  https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1beta1?id=123  Usually the access token is a parameter. Capture working request with fiddler and check the URL parameters.